# Having trouble passing data through RF24

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, timers, nrf24l01+

I have three RF24, all of them are connected to one arduino-uno each. The first one has sensors that sends data to the second one then the second one passes it to the third one. The first pass from RF24 #1 to RF24 #2 is successful but from the RF24 #2 to RF24 #3 there seems to be a problem.

Code for the RF24 #1 (I just copied the setup and loop the other functions are for the sensors, I think it's unnecessary):

```
//Libraries for temperature
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define motor1 8
// Data wire is plugged into port 2 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

//for pH meter
#define SensorPin A0            //pH meter Analog output to Arduino Analog Input 0
#define Offset 0.00            //deviation compensate
#define LED 13
#define samplingInterval 20
#define printInterval 800
#define ArrayLenth  40    //times of collection
int pHArray[ArrayLenth];   //Store the average value of the sensor feedback
int pHArrayIndex = 0;

//for NRF24L01
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const uint64_t waddress = 0xB00B1E50D2LL;
struct package {
  float temperature, ph, Do, inch, cm1;
};
typedef struct package Package;
Package data;
int LID = 4, LOD = 6;

//for ultrasonic
const int trigPin = 3;
const int echoPin = 4;
long duration, inches, cm, meter;


void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(waddress);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();
}

/*
   Main function, get and show the temperature
*/


void loop(void)
{
  static unsigned long samplingTime = millis();
  static unsigned long printTime = millis();
  static float pHValue, voltage;
  if (millis() - samplingTime > samplingInterval)
  {
    pHArray[pHArrayIndex++] = analogRead(SensorPin);
    if (pHArrayIndex == ArrayLenth)pHArrayIndex = 0;
    voltage = avergearray(pHArray, ArrayLenth) * 5.0 / 1024;
    pHValue = 3.5 * voltage + Offset;
    samplingTime = millis();
  }
  if (millis() - printTime > printInterval)  //Every 800 milliseconds, print a numerical, convert the state of the LED indicator
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, digitalRead(LED) ^ 1);
    // call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature
    // request to all devices on the bus

    sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperatures

    // After we got the temperatures, we can print them here.
    // We use the function ByIndex, and as an example get the temperature from the first sensor only.

    //Serial.print(pHValue,2);
    //Serial.print(",");
    //Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));

    radio.write(&data, sizeof(data));

    data.ph = (pHValue);
    data.temperature = (sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
    Serial.print(data.ph);
    Serial.print(data.temperature);
    Serial.print(data.Do);
  }
}
```

RF24 #2

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const uint64_t raddress = 0xB00B1E50D2LL;
const uint64_t waddress = 0xB00B1E50B1LL;
struct package {
  float temperature, ph, Do, inch, cm1;
};
typedef struct package Package;
Package data;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(waddress);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, raddress);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
}


void loop() {
  radio.startListening();

  while (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
    Serial.print(data.ph);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.temperature);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.Do);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.inch);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(data.cm1);
  }
  if (radio.write(&data, sizeof(data))) {
    Serial.println(" delivery failed");
  }
  radio.stopListening();
  delay(200);
}
```

RF24 #3

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
int lid = 2 , lod = 4;
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const uint64_t raddress = 0xB00B1E50B1LL;
struct package {
  float temperature, ph, Do, inch, cm1;
};
typedef struct package Package;
Package data;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, raddress);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
  pinMode(lid, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lod, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  unsigned long startTimer = millis();
  bool timeout = false;

  while (!radio.available() && !timeout) {
    if (millis() - startTimer > 500 )
    {
      timeout = true;
    }
    // radio.read(&temperature, sizeof(temperature));
    //radio.read(&Do, sizeof(Do));
  }
  if (timeout) {
    Serial.println("Failed to receive data");
  }
  else {
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));

    Serial.print(data.ph);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.temperature);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.Do);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.inch);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(data.cm1);
  }
}
```

The serial monitor for RF24 #2 displays:

```
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
6.92,28.25,7.20,15.00,38.00
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
 delivery failed
6.91,28.25,7.20,15.00,38.00
```

RF24 #3 Serial Monitor:

```
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
```

Sometimes RF24 #3 receives the data and prints it continuously. I don't know why. Most of the time it displays the above.

Edit: Revision

Update: It turns out that RF24 #3 continuous to print even if RF24 #2 is unplugged/not powered.

Answer (score 0):

You should always call `stopListening()` right before you `write()`. Also `write()` returns true when messages are delivered so your condition is wrong. Try changing the `loop()` in the second node to:

```
void loop() {   
  while (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
    Serial.print(data.ph);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.temperature);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.Do);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.inch);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(data.cm1);

    radio.stopListening();
    if (!radio.write(&data, sizeof(data))) {
      Serial.println("Delivery failed");
    }
    radio.startListening();
  }
}
```

If a packet is available, it's read, printed and forwarded.
The third node's `loop()` should also be adjusted to something like:

```
bool new_data = false;

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));

    Serial.print(data.ph);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.temperature);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.Do);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(data.inch);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(data.cm1);
    new_data = true;
  }
  if (new_data) {
    // do stuff
    new_data = false;
  }
}
```

Data is sent in 32-byte payloads and your entire package is 20 bytes (without padding), assuming a float = 4 bytes. So a complete packet has either arrived or it hasn't; no point in waiting in one place. `new_data` lets you know when there's new stuff obviously and you clear the flag when you're done processing the data. This way, you can do other stuff while you wait for a packet to show.